# I subsetted a list of words from a larger list of 72 items. How do I determine what list number (1-72) those words came from?

Tags: r, string

I imported 720 sentences from this website (https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/harvard.html). There are 72 lists (each list contains 10 sentences.) and saved it in an appropriate structure. I did those step in R. The code is immediately depicted below.

```
#Q.1a
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/harvard.html'
sentences <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_text()
headers <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("h2") %>%
  html_text()

#Q.1b
harvardList <- list()
sentenceList <- list()
n <- 1

for(sentence in sentences){
  sentenceList <- c(sentenceList, sentence)
  print(sentence)
  if(length(sentenceList) == 10) { #if we have 10 sentences
    harvardList[[headers[n]]] <- sentenceList #Those 10 sentences and the respective list from which they are derived, are appended to the harvard list
    sentenceList <- list() #emptying our temporary list which those 10 sentences were shuffled into
    n <- n+1 #set our list name to the next one
  }
}

#Q.1c
sentences1 <- split(sentences, ceiling(seq_along(sentences)/10))
getwd()
setwd("/Users/juliayudkovicz/Documents/Homework 4 Datascience")
sentences.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(sentences1, as.data.frame))
names(sentences.df)[1] <- "Sentences"
write.csv(sentences.df, file = "sentences1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

THEN, in PYTHON, I computed a list of all the words ending in "ing" and what their frequency was, aka, how many times they appeared across all 72 lists.

```
path="/Users/juliayudkovicz/Documents/Homework 4 Datascience"
os.chdir(path)
cwd1 = os.getcwd()
print(cwd1)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/juliayudkovicz/Documents/Homework 4 Datascience/sentences1.csv', sep='\t', engine='python')
print(df)
df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].str.replace(".", "")
print(df)
sen_List = df['Sentences'].values.tolist()
print(sen_List)

ingWordList = [];
for line in sen_List:
    for word in line.split():
         if word.endswith('ing'):
                ingWordList.append(word)

ingWordCountDictionary = {};

for word in ingWordList:
    word = word.replace('"', "")
    word = word.lower()
    if word in ingWordCountDictionary:
        ingWordCountDictionary[word] = ingWordCountDictionary[word] + 1
    else: 
        ingWordCountDictionary[word] = 1

print(ingWordCountDictionary)

f = open("ingWordCountDictionary.txt", "w")

for key, value in ingWordCountDictionary.items():
    keyValuePairToWrite = "%s, %s\n"%(key, value)
    f.write(keyValuePairToWrite)


f.close()
```

Now, I am being asked to create a dataset which shows what list (1 from 72) each "ing" word is derived from. THIS IS WHAT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO. I obviously know they are a subset of huge 72 item list, but how do I figure out what list those words came from.

The expected output should look something like this:

```
[List Number] [-ing Word]
List 1        swing, ring, etc.,
List 2        moving
```

so and so forth

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post by removing its content. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275864/1288408 for further information

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please read up on how to use Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience. Two people here posted answers, as volunteers in their free time. Trying to get this question deleted invalidates their work. Saying that nobody is helping and that it is useless is not true. Your answer pointing to another post is not what SO considers a valid answer. Please _try_ to value the community by being open to learn how to use Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: I just saw that you even tried to delete an answer by changing its text. That's big no go. Value the time of users trying to help.

Comment: lol then why was it the only answer that got the output required for my assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way for you. As far as I see the expected result, you seem to want to get verbs in progressive forms (V-ing). (I do not understand why you have king in your result. If you have king, you should have spring here as well, for example.) If you need to consider lexical classes, I think you want to use the `koRpus` package. If not, you can use the `textstem` package, for example.

First, I scraped the link and created a data frame. Then, I split sentences into words using `unnest_tokens()` in the `tidytext` package, and subsetted words ending with 'ing'. Then, I used `treetag()` in the koRpus package. You need to install Treetagger by yourself before you use the package. Finally, I counted how many times these verbs in progressive forms appear in the data set. I hope this will help you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(tidytext)
library(koRpus)

read_html("https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/harvard.html") %>% 
  html_nodes("h2") %>% 
  html_text() -> so_list

read_html("https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/harvard.html") %>% 
  html_nodes("li") %>% 
  html_text() -> so_text


# Create a data frame

sodf <- tibble(list_name = rep(so_list, each = 10),
           text = so_text)

# Split senteces into words and get words ending with ING.

unnest_tokens(sodf, input = text, output = word) %>% 
  filter(grepl(x = word, pattern = "ing$")) -> sowords

# Use koRpus package to lemmatize the words in sowords$word.

treetag(sowords$word, treetagger = "manual", format = "obj",
        TT.tknz = FALSE , lang = "en", encoding = "UTF-8",
        TT.options = list(path = "C:\\tree-tagger-windows-3.2\\TreeTagger",
                          preset = "en")) -> out

# Access to the data frame and filter the words. It seems that you are looking
# for verbs. So I did that here.

filter(out@TT.res, grepl(x = token, pattern = "ing$") & wclass == "verb") %>% 
  count(token)

# A tibble: 16 x 2
#   token         n
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 adding        1
# 2 bring         4
# 3 changing      1
# 4 drenching     1
# 5 dying         1
# 6 lodging       1
# 7 making        1
# 8 raging        1
# 9 shipping      1
#10 sing          1
#11 sleeping      2
#12 wading        1
#13 waiting       1
#14 wearing       1
#15 winding       2
#16 working       1
```

Comment: Hi, I just posted a snippet of the dataset with frequencies. There are actually 36 words ending "ing".

Comment: My question is how can I go back and determine what list those words are derived from.

Comment: @help So that means, you do not have to check lexical class. You do not have to count frequency either. Is that right?

Comment: If what I said is the case, `unnest_tokens(sodf, input = text, output = word) %>% 
  filter(grepl(x = word, pattern = "ing$"))` returns the result you want. Some words have dupes. So you have 52 rows with 36 unique words in the result. By the way, when you ask any questions, you want to clearly provide expected results. Otherwise, SO users will not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: No, I  do have to count frequency, but I already did that. I'm asking for help on a different part.

Comment: @help Then, I wonder why you added the figure in your question. That seems to drive SO users in unexpected directions. At least, I was driven in that way.

Comment: because someone else asked to see it

Answer (score 0):

How did you store the data from the lists (ie what does your data.frame look like? Could you provide an example?

Without seeing this, I suggest you save the data in a list as follows:

```
COLUMN 1   ,   COLUMN 2,   COLUMN 3 
"List number", "Sentence", "-ING words (as vector)"
```

I hope this makes sense, let me know if you need more help. I wasn't able to comment on this post unfortunately.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: you can' comment unless you have 50 rep, a bit silly in this case

Comment: Hi @Alex I provided more information in my question! and G5W, at least he's trying to help me

Comment: Yeah, having look at that, its best if you parse this into a dataframe with the structure I outlined above. If you need help doing this let me know. You should have a new row per ING word when all is done. Then you will be able to see where the sentence originated.